# windows server 2008: How to identify who is logged on to the server

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

My windows server 2008 allows only one user to login at a given time. When another user tries to remote login into the same server, the previously active user's session gets disconnected. This is creating few problems for us.

Can anyone tell me a way to find whether a user has already logged into the server/ to find currently active user without actually having to login into the server so that the already active user's session will not be disturbed.

Pl provide your valuable thoughts.

Comment: belongs to serverfault really

Comment: have a look at this question : http://serverfault.com/questions/371487/can-i-monitor-active-user-count-on-my-iis-sites

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 type of users interactive (which you are looking for?) and non-interactive (System, batch, network etc.)
So there is an API [Win32_LogonSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which you can see. also there is a good article on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7483/Enumerating-Logon-Sessions